# Android camera capture bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

In my android coding I have a camera surface view class, when I show the preview for this camera class it's a live camera scene, but how can I create a function that create a bitmap for the camera current frame?
So I can get the captured bitmap from other class.

Any guidance will be appreciated~

This is my camera class coding:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Camera mCamera;
boolean isPreviewRunning = false;

CameraSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    SurfaceHolder mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized(this) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Camera", "mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);");
        }
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    synchronized(this) {
        try {
            if (mCamera!=null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                isPreviewRunning=false;
                mCamera.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Camera", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that below codes are for **capturing** image with its displayed pixels, not for **taking camera**. It means, the result image will give actual pixel size of the *screen* (ie, 1080x768), not multi-megapixel high resolution image of the Camera app. If you want to take an image as Camera app provided, use [takePicture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)) method.

In order to capture live preview image in `SurfaceView`,

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraSurfaceView";

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Context mContext;
    private Camera.Parameters mParameters;
    private byte[] byteArray;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraSurfaceView (Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CameraSurfaceView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CameraSurfaceView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;

        try {
            mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
            mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
            } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
            }
        }

        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (mCamera != null)
                mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        if (mCamera == null) {
                return;
        } else {
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                    if (mParameters == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    byteArray = bytes;
                }
            });
        }

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {
        try {
            mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<Size> cameraSize = mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            mPreviewSize = cameraSize.get(0);

            for (Size s : cameraSize) {
                if ((s.width * s.height) > (mPreviewSize.width * mPreviewSize.height)) {
                    mPreviewSize = s;
                }
            }

            mParameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        try {
            if (mParameters == null)
                return null;

            if (mPreviewSize == null)
                return null;

            int format = mParameters.getPreviewFormat();
            YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(byteArray, format, mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(rect, 75, byteArrayOutputStream);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), 0, byteArrayOutputStream.size(), options);

            byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mBitmap;
    }

    public Camera getCamera() {
        return mCamera;
    }
}
```

Comment: what means if I missed the mPreviewSize?

Comment: @LeParkour // sorry for my short English. the description editted.

Comment: In the getBitmap function cannot resolve byteArray symbol

Comment: @LeParkour // editted. just define `byte[] byteArray`

Comment: Sir, when I call the getBitmap function I get java.lang.NullPointerException error

Comment: @LeParkour // which line or field did you get?

Comment: I get error in another class like this: newBitmap = cameraclass.getBitmap();

Comment: @LeParkour // Call ` cameraclass.getBitmap().startPreview();` once again in _another class_. Or, I recommend you to find which line make it returns _null_ in cameraclass.

Comment: sorry my mistake I forget to put this line cameraclass = new CameraSurfaceView(context); and now I get new error line which is the mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();

Comment: @LeParkour // Note that, you have to test it with real device. Or, more than three device as Camera api is really unstable and usually throw `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Ya, i using real device to run it, but i get error in line mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.etoff.appsopengl.CameraSurfaceView.getBitmap(CameraSurfaceView.java: line 33 mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();)

Comment: @LeParkour // add my `surfaceCreated` method. hope it can solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I forget to update my surface created code, it's by following your code?

Comment: @LeParkour // yes, my code. let me remove listener that you do not have.

Comment: @LeParkour // fixed. sorry.

Comment: this time more worse the camera can't start error line was  mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

Comment: where should I put this 2 lines? mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();

Comment: that's almost all of my code. Do not just copy and paste. I recommend you to read line by line and adopt to yours.

Comment: mParameters = mCamera.getParameters(); this is still the error

Comment: Please try with other devices. Or, clean all processes before running your app.

Comment: @LeParkour // I hardly find your error. but let me give you ALL of my code. Whatever you have error, I do not know afterwards.

Comment: Ya, It's work, but the capture image is empty 0 bytes

Comment: Sir can u tell me how you call getbitmap function in other class? why i get a zero empty picture?

Comment: Did you check `mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height` give values well? or, did you check every point of variables such as `format`, `byteArray`, `yuvImage`, `byteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: I tried manually change the mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height but still get same empty bitmap

Comment: what about other variables?

Comment: If I call like this ok? CameraSurfaceView csv;
                    csv = new CameraSurfaceView(getContext());
                    imgB = csv.getBitmap();

Comment: Sir thanks alot, now totally worked...... last time is null because i call a empty camera view.... but now I have a new problem again that's the captured image is rotated landscape, my android manifest is portrait, but i dunwan to change my android manifest, any way to rotate the camera? im using setDisplayOrientation but the raw data not changed

Comment: @LeParkour // that's out of this question topic. you may post a question again for that.

Comment: but do you have solution for this, this question in stackoverflow people asked before, but when i use the solution the output image i get is distorted with some green color

Comment: they rotate the byte array

Comment: @LeParkour // similar to that. I'm using `matrix.postRotate(degree);` for rotating image.

Comment: this method just rotate the image angle view, i mean my problem is totally stretch inside the camera, the raw data byte array is not following the setdisplayorientation to 90 when capture

Comment: @LeParkour // hello, ask in another question or link what you asked please. this is out of focus in this context.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm!