# How to capture screenshot of camera preview with overlay?

Tags: android, android-camera

I saw the following link for the above query but both the answers does not met the expectation.

[[How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android][1])

Expectation: Capture camera preview with overlay.

Comment: so u want to capture the photo shown in the camera preview?

Comment: Capture an image from the Camera using the standard API into a Bitmap. Create a Canvas for the Bitmap, then draw the overlay with that Canvas. Save the Bitmap. If that doesn't work for you, you'll need to explain your requirements in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

I provided solution to a folk, please [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092744/android-camera-capture-bitmap/33093035#33093035). He had trouble to get the result but copied code below is what I'm using in production since a year ago. please try it.

The code captures image in `SurfaceView` which is given from `Camera`. You can overlay some views on it. They will be captured along with Camera preview.

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraSurfaceView";

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Context mContext;
    private Camera.Parameters mParameters;
    private byte[] byteArray;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraSurfaceView (Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CameraSurfaceView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CameraSurfaceView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;

        try {
            mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
            mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
            } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
            }
        }

        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (mCamera != null)
                mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        if (mCamera == null) {
                return;
        } else {
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
                    if (mParameters == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    byteArray = bytes;
                }
            });
        }

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {
        try {
            mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            List<Size> cameraSize = mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            mPreviewSize = cameraSize.get(0);

            for (Size s : cameraSize) {
                if ((s.width * s.height) > (mPreviewSize.width * mPreviewSize.height)) {
                    mPreviewSize = s;
                }
            }

            mParameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        try {
            if (mParameters == null)
                return null;

            if (mPreviewSize == null)
                return null;

            int format = mParameters.getPreviewFormat();
            YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(byteArray, format, mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(rect, 75, byteArrayOutputStream);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPurgeable = true;
            options.inInputShareable = true;
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), 0, byteArrayOutputStream.size(), options);

            byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mBitmap;
    }

    public Camera getCamera() {
        return mCamera;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello can you provide full code implementation there are some errors can't resolved in this class